# r specifying random effects

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I have a dataset with repeated measurements among participants (Subjects).

Each subject is tied to a Site (Iowa, Kansas, Tennessee, ....). A subject can only be in one Site and does not appear in two different sites.  { *A participant is only in one State. Cannot appear in two states at the same time.*}

My goal is to

a) estimate random intercepts for both Site and Subject.

b) Nest the subject under their respective Sites

So is this correct ?

```
lme4::lmer(outcome ~ a1 + x1 + (1 | SiteID / SubjectID), data=df)
```

Thanks in advance for any advise.

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful to have a sample of your data to be certain, but your specification looks correct to me.